# php - single quotes around variables in mysql queries

Tags: php, mysql, syntax, quotes

Why do I see in several examples of mysql queries via php the syntax:

```
$q = "CREATE TABLE '$tablename' ('$t_id_name')";
```

or things similar to that? I'm asking about the single quotes around the variable names. Is this required in MySQL strings? If I echo the string, it seems to expand the variables whether the quotes are there or not.

And would this pose a problem if this were done for something that was intended to be an integer?

Comment: Stop thinking about them as variable names, simply because you're using variables in your code; this is a MySQL statement you're building. Use backticks (`), not single quotes (') to wrap table and column names in MySQL (though you only need them if they are MySQL reserved words, mixed case or use non-Alphanumeric characters)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your question, the quotes are necessary, but not to expand the variable. A typical SQL query would look like this:

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `first_name` = 'user3475234'";
```

Now, consider the following example:

```
<?php
$tablename = "users";
$user = "user3475234";

$q = "SELECT * FROM `$tablename` WHERE `first_name` = '$user'";

echo $q;
```

This will display: `` SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `first_name` = 'user3475234' ``. Note that the quotes weren't necessary to output the string, but they were a necessary part of the query.

That being said, code like this opens your script to SQL injection. I won't explain too much about it, since there are plenty of resources discussing it, but consider the example where someone's username is `user3475234' OR 1==1--`. This username will effectively return all users in the table.

Comment: I'm curious as to whether you intentionally typed ` and ' separately? Is there preferred use of one over the other or are they both just supposed to be just regular single quotes? Also, I'm using mysqli_real_escape_string for now to avoid the SQL injection that comes with this (but I don't think it checks for the ` character).

Comment: Backticks are used for table names and column names, and are only necessary when the table or column name is a reserved MySQL keyword. Values, on the other hand, are surrounded by quotes.

Answer (score 2):

You must use backticks (`) for field or table name especially if the field or table name are same with mysql command. And you need to use single-quote (') for value.